# How Would One Grab N Unique Items From Array Under These Conditions....?

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, heap

### Summary

---

I've been trying to help someone with this problem for two days now and while I can brute force it with nested for loops, I'm trying to simplify it to two ***non-nested*** loops.

Here are the conditions:

- Use a map to store the index of an item's first appearance and the number of appearances in the array
- The caller of the method must be able to specify the first N unique elements to grab
- Not allowed to have more than 2 loops, also, they should **NOT** be nested

### My Attempt

---

```
public  <E extends Comparable<E>> void getHeapUnique(E[] array, int n) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<>();
        int count = 0;
        boolean unique = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            // here is where I get stuck

        }

        for (Integer key : map.keySet())
        {
            if (count==2)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (map.get(key) == 1)
            {
                heap.add((Integer) array[key]);
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(heap.toString());
    }
```

### Questions

---

So, I'm led to believe that a heap data structure might hold some key into simplifying or providing behavior that I'm not aware of that would unravel this mystery. Would implementing a heap provide special powers I'm not aware of?

I specifically am told to store the index of a numbers first appearance and the number of appearances in a map. I'm also told not to loop over the array, but the map instead. I have no problem doing this but my problem is that I can only imagine a method of determining if the item
has already appeared if I use a nested loop to check every single key in the map's key set:

```
...
for (int i  = 0; i < arr.length;i++)
{
   boolean unique = true;

   for (Integer index : map.keySet())
   {
      if (arr[i] == arr[index])
      {
          unique = false;
          int incr = map.get(index) + 1;
          map.put(index, incr);
          break;
      }
   }

   if (unique)
   {
      map.put(i, 1);
      count++;
      if (count == n)
      {
         break;
      }
   }
}
...
```

What am I missing here?